# Routing Issue Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a routing issue. On articles#index I have a list of articles grouped by category. The title of the article needs to link to the article on articles#show. I need to make sure the links of the articles have the account id because when I link to the article on articles#show the url needs to read www.example.com/accounts/1/articles/1

These are the model associations

```
    class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
      extend FriendlyId
      friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

      belongs_to :feed
      has_one :category, :through => :feed
      has_one :account, :through => :feed
    end

    class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

      has_many :feeds, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :articles, through: :feeds
    end

    class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base

      belongs_to :account
      belongs_to :category
      has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy
   end

   class Category < ActiveRecord::Base      
      has_many :feeds
      has_many :articles, through: :feeds
   end
```

Articles index view:

```
<% @article_list.each do |category, article_items| %>
  <h1><%= category %></h1> 
  <% article_items.last(5).each do |article_item| %>
    <p><%= link_to article_item.name, account_articles_path(:account_id) %></p>

    <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

routes:

```
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  resources :accounts do    
    resources :articles
  end
```

account_articles_path(:account_id) doesn't work.

articles controller:

```
  def index
    @articles = Article.includes(:category)
    @article_list = @articles.group_by { |t| t.category.name }
  end
```

Comment: What's your `config/routes.rb` look like?

Comment: I just added it to the question. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using nested resources, your route expects two parameters, the first one being the `account`, and the second being the `article`:

```
link_to article_item.name, account_article_path(article_item.account, article_item)
```

The syntax may be slightly different, but that's the general idea.

Comment: I'm getting undefined method `account' for nil:NilClass, i'm not sure why your code seems correct. The association works because in rails console for example I do a = Article.first then a.account and it brings up the account that has that article.

Comment: almost there. it works except instead of www.example.com/account/account_id/articles/article_id it is showing www.example.com/account/account_id/articles.article_id so without the / it doesn't link. do you know why its adding a . instead of a / before the article_id?

Comment: I just figured it out. it is account_article_path instead of account_articles_path. Thanks for your help!